# Simplify for loop for the iteration (using the crate strum)

Tags: for-loop, enums, rust

I have a question about how a could simplify my code

I am using the crate strum (https://docs.rs/strum/0.17.1/strum/) and my question is how to simplify .iter() (macro EnumIter) to the array number without passing in a for loop

Const file :

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Display, EnumIter)]
pub enum Signs {
    Aries = 1,
    Taurus = 2,
    Gemini = 3,
    Cancer = 4,
    Leo = 5,
    Virgo = 6,
    Libra = 7,
    Scorpio = 8,
    Sagittarius = 9,
    Capricorn = 10,
    Aquarius = 11,
    Pisces = 12,
}
```

And the code:

```
extern crate math;
use crate::sweconst::Signs;
use math::round;
use strum::IntoEnumIterator;
pub fn myfunction(ddeg: f64) -> Signs {
    // Convert deg to sign 30°
    let sign_calc = round::half_up(ddeg / 30.0, 0) as i32;

    // And the ugly code
    let mut sign = Signs::Aries;
    let mut i = 0;
    for s in Signs::iter() {
        i += 1;
        if i == sign_calc as i32 {
            sign = s;
            break;
        }
    }
    sign
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`Iterator::enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate):

```rust
for (i, s) in Signs::iter().enumerate() {
    if (i + 1) == sign_calc {
        sign = s;
        break;
    }
}
```

The `i` here is zero-based, so you may need to adjust the code accordingly.

---

It can, indeed, be further simplified and made easier to read:

```rust
pub fn myfunction(ddeg: f64) -> Signs {
    let sign_calc = round::half_up(ddeg / 30.0, 0) as usize;

    Signs::iter().nth(sign_calc - 1).unwrap_or(Signs::Aries)
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, is it possible to simplify on one line ?

Comment: @Stéphane sure, but I'm not gonna tell you :P

Comment: It works fine ! Sorry I made a mistake, it is not round::half_up, simply round::floor. So don't need to + 1 or - 1